# The top reseller hosts with unlimited web space and bandwidth

Tags: web-hosting, reseller

Hi I'm looking at finding myself a reseller hosting plan (preferably based in the UK) and I wondering if anyone knows of any good reseller hosts that provide **UNLIMITED** disk space and bandwidth.

The only UK host I seem able to find that matches this description is heartinternet.co.uk. Are there any others you would recommend?

P.S. Hosts with cPanel get a +1 !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of [All cPanel Partners](http://www.cpanel.net/apps/partners/partner-lookup.cgi?showall=1) - you'll find many options* for just about any location.

I counted 9-10 hosts with "UK" in their company name, but search on "United Kingdom" (41 results) to get more results.

*
Note: "Unlimited" anything is a marketing gimmick - I would wager you'll be much better off working with a host which is up-front about its policies and practices.

Comment: I sorta agree with you on the "unlimited" bandwidth/storage thing, but you'd still be better off going with a company that advertises "unlimited" versus 20/30GB of bandwidth. Generally speaking, the unlimited bandwidth plans are called "unlimited" because they're effectively unlimited in most cases. That means the web host allows a ridiculously high bandwidth/storage quota where the bottleneck is usually CPU cycles, not bandwidth/storage.

Comment: This also means that the web host doesn't need to allot 2TB of storage for every single user, since most users won't use anywhere close to that amount. Instead, users start off with much less, and if they fill it up, the web host can add more or move them to a different server. This saves the web host money and gives them the ability to accommodate users with much greater storage needs.

Comment: "... or move them to a different server" - Yes, however, the tendency there is to move the user to a server with other users who are stressing available resources (i.e. to "isolate the problem") and performance suffers accordingly. It's unlikely that a provider which touts hosting without limits will disclose when this action has been taken (or even the thresholds which trigger the action) and, as such, a forthright cap offers less guesswork and degraded performance for users who really need more resources than $9.99/mo will buy.

Comment: Agreeing here. 'Unlimited' bandwidth would not be used, for example. Even a large amount of it, because to use that, you would also be using surely web apps that would use a lot of cpu usage, and hostings are quick to stop you from using a lot of cpu. Their TOS usually detail actions to be taken in several cases. Even they actually disallow by default the usage of certain services, to prevent this. But I'd as well would take Unlimited hosting, if it's reported to be good. I have been reading a lot that Hostgator is good to go, but don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 1):

Unlimited? good luck with that one. There are no hosting providers with unlimited space and bandwidth. This is just slang mouthy language that is blurted out all the time. In this life, everything has a limit. You had better start reading the fine print or you will eventually find yourself in a pickle.